# Update column as I loop through all rows

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update

I am looking to update 1 column for each row as I loop through all of them.  I have something built out however I know its not correct.  It will work only if a record is never deleted and a new one added.  Where it runs into a problem is if a row is deleted and that _id no longer exists, it will try to update that row anyways because it is just looping through a "key" and does "key++" at the end.

```
public void updateMPG(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("select (x.odometer - y.odometer) / x.gallons as mpg from gasLog x, gasLog y where y.odometer = (select max(z.odometer) from gasLog z where z.odometer < x.odometer)", null);
        Cursor cursor2 = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT odometer FROM gasLog", null);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        try {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            cursor2.moveToFirst();
            int key = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0 && (cursor2.getString(0) != getOdometerReading())){
                    mpg = cursor.getString(0);
                    values.put(KEY_MPG, mpg);
                    db.update(TABLE_GASLOG, values, "_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(key)});
                } else {
                    values.put(KEY_MPG, 0);
                    db.update(TABLE_GASLOG, values, "_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(key)});
                }

                if (cursor.isLast())
                    break;
                cursor.moveToNext();
                cursor2.moveToNext();
                key++;
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        db.close();

    }
```

As you can see, it will loop through the rows as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc... however if you delete a record (say row 3) and create a new row.. row 7, it will never get to row 7.  It will only loop through 1, 2, 3(no longer exists), 4, 5, 6..

Anyone have an idea as far as how I could have it update the current row which the cursor is on?

If you need any additional details, please let me know.

Thanks

EDIT: Delete code

```
public void deleteGasLog(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_GASLOG, //table name
                KEY_ID + " = ?",  // selections
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }); //selections args
        db.close();

    }
```

Comment: where is your deletion code ?

Comment: and are you sure you're inserting the new record in database ?

Comment: It should be possible to do the entire thing with a single UPDATE statement. What is your goal?

Comment: my dear it is not possible a code is getting all the records first time and not getting next time, code is perfect but make sure you are following the right procedure, get records from database , del a record, insert new record (make sure it is inserting) and then get again. It should work without any error

Comment: if you can write insertion code , and how you are using this, then might be we can solve it

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the `_id` column to your query so that you can read the correct value for the current row.

However, the following statement will update all `mpg` values at once:

```sql
UPDATE gasLog
SET mpg = COALESCE((odometer - (SELECT odometer
                                FROM gasLog AS G2
                                WHERE odometer < gasLog.odometer
                                ORDER BY odometer DESC
                                LIMIT 1)) / gallons,
                   0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Once the cursor is retrieved from the query, it has nothing to do with the actual database, besides representing the db's data. Even if you were able to change the row in a cursor, which you are not able to, it wouldn't effect the database.

Comment: It *is* possible to update the database row that is represented by a row in the cursor.